# Isomorphic factor rings of polynomial rings does imply isomorphic ideals?

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomials, ideals

Let $k$ be a field, $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $R=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. If $R/I\simeq R/J$ as rings, then $I \simeq J$ as $R$-modules holds?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If both $I$ and $J$ are maximal and $R/I \simeq R/J$ as k-algebras, then $I\simeq J$ as k-algebras holds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The claim is not true.  A counterexample:

Let $R=k[w,x,y,z]$, $I=(w,x)$, and $J=(y,z)$.  Notice that $R/I\cong R/J$ as rings.  Now, suppose that $I\cong J$ as $R$-modules and let $f:I\to J$ be an isomorphism.

Then $0=f(xw-wx)=xf(w)-wf(x)$ so that $xf(w)=wf(x)$.  By unique factorization in $R$, it follows that $f(w)=wp$ and $f(x)=xp$ for some $p\in R$.  Since $f$ is an isomorphism, it is surjective, so there must exist $a,b\in R$ with:

$$y=f(aw+bx)=af(w)+bf(x)=(aw+bx)p$$

Looking at degrees, we arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Why your $f$ can't be just $f(w)=y$ and $f(x)=z$?

Comment: @SashaPatotski: Notice that $I$ is not a free $R$-module, we have the relation $x\cdot w=w\cdot x$.  The resulting relation in $J$ is then $x\cdot f(w)=w\cdot f(x)$, so whatever we choose for $f(w)$ and $f(x)$ must satisfy this relation.

Comment: @Jared I am sorry, you are right.

Comment: What's the problem with the degrees in order to get a contradiction? From $y=(aw+bx)p$ it follows that $y=0$ by sending $x$ and $w$ to $0$.